# Generate barcode from arabic characters using C#

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-printing

I need to generate a barcode at sometime using my web application, and i need to store Arabic text in it.

Then i want any person to be able to read the barcode and show the data in a notepad without the need of using a third tool to decrypt the data.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: Generate a QR code with Arabic text, e.g. https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=%D9%87%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%83%20%D9%8A%D9%82%D9%88%D9%85%20%D9%88%D9%8A%D8%B9%D8%B2%D9%89&chs=180x180&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|2 (I have no idea what the text means.)

Comment: @codo  the barcode example u just post it is not what i want because when i try to read it, it shows unknown characters not arabic

Answer (score 2):

*Bar*codes (as in: 1D) can only contain the characters specified in their specification. For example, EAN13 can only hold numbers, Code128 can contain numbers, US-ASCII letters and some special characters, etc.

If you are talking about 1D-*Bar*codes, look into their definition. I know of no 1D-barcode that can hold unicode (specifically arabic) letters.

QR-codes should be able to contain unicode characters. Both the application that generates the QR-code and the application that interprets the QR-code need to be able to use UTF8/16 encoding, however.

It might help to add a BOM (byte-order-mark) that indicates which type of unicode character set the content is encoded in. The interpreting application might consider this to use the proper text encoding for displaying the contents of the barcode.